# Testflight issue: can only install app on devices that were plugged in directly

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

This is a strange issue we're currently having.

We uploaded a new version of our application to itunes connect, and we sent it to the internal testers. However, only those where we installed some version of the application directly through XCode at some point are the ones who can install it via testflight.

Our devices where the app has never been directly installed through XCode cannot install the game right now through testflight (the download gets to around 98% and the says that it was unable to install, even if they had downloaded a previous version of the application through Testflight successfully at some point).

So, I'm assuming, maybe there's something in the XCode settings? It seems like something quite specific.

Comment: Did you increased build number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should sign your application with an **Ad-hoc profile**, **not** the developer and **not** the AppStore one. To make sure it is about provision or certificate signing, with your device connected to computer, in XCode, open device manager and see log while you are trying to install app via Testflight.

Comment: Actually, this might be the problem since Adhoc profiles contain the specific UDID's of the devices that the app can be installed on. If anything, make sure the app IS NOT signed with an Adhoc profile. Also, delete any previous instances of the app on the device.

Comment: cbiggin if he added users in Testflight as internal users, the UUID does not matter anymore.

Comment: You're right. After using the ad-hoc profile I was able to install it.

And yes, the UUIDs aren't necessary anymore when using the new Testflight through itunes connect.